# How to apply the color from selected theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using https://material-ui-next.com/ as following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppBar, Toolbar } from 'material-ui';
import { Typography } from 'material-ui';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import {cyan, blue} from 'material-ui/colors';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary:{
      main:blue[900]
    },
    secondary: cyan, 
  },
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="title">
            Hello
          </Typography>          
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

As you can see, I changed the primary theme to

```
main:blue[900]
```

But the font color is black. How to change the font color to white?
Looking at https://material-ui-next.com/style/color/, that the font color is white.

The output is:
[image]

The font color is black but I want to change to white.

Comment: Can you add some little bit more information what actually you  want to do?

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `theme` object to:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: blue[900]
    },
    text: {
      primary: '#fff',
    }
  }
});
```

Reference: https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/

Comment: Where did you find it? I was searching for too, but could not find it.